# How do I pre-populate a squid proxy with a Ubuntu installation?

Tags: installation, proxy, squid

I have an installation service in a central data centre and proxies in other data centres and need to pre-populate those proxies with the contents of the installation.

What's the best way to do this?

I've been thinking of writing a script along the lines of:

- `debootstrap` - with `--include` option to include all additional packages above and beyond the minimal setup, run this once inside each DC to populate the proxy.
- `apt-proxy-import - apt-proxy` can add debs directly into the cache, take them from an existing installs /var/cache/apt/archives dir.
- Take the cache miss and have a slow first install?

Comment: As part of the site cleanup your question has been flagged, are you still having the issue or resolved it yourself with the script you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [apt-proxy](http://apt-proxy.sourceforge.net/) or [apt-cacher-ng](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/) instead of squid? To make use of squid's caching, you could allow either of those through squid to the internet. All you'd have to do is to point your /etc/apt/sources.list to the correct apt-proxy/apt-cacher-ng servers. Ubuntu has an excellent wiki page on apt-proxy - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptProxy